# How does this closure work when using JQuery clone() and selecting descendant element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-clone

In the below code when the user clicks the "click me" div a new list item is "cloned" and it works the way I would expect.

[JSfiddle_1](http://jsfiddle.net/odpp0t2a/1/)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="button">Click me</div>
        <div class="template">
            <li>oink</li>
        </div>

    <ul>
    </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){

    var result = $('.template li').clone(); //______Descendant selector
    $("ul").append(result);
});
```

---

However, in the version of the code below I modified the code to not have a descendant selector. In this version when you click the "click me" div the number of elements is compounded on each click which tells me a closure is happening, but what I don't understand is why this doesn't happen when adding a descendant selector. Any clarification is appreciated. Thank you

[JSfiddle_2](http://jsfiddle.net/odpp0t2a/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">Click me</div>
    <div class="template">
        <li>oink</li>
    </div>

<ul>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){

    var result = $('li').clone(); //______No descendant selector
    $("ul").append(result);
});
```

Comment: `$('.template li')` is exactly one `<li />` element. `$('li')` contains **all** `<li />` elements found in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.template li')` selects descendant `<li>s` of just the `.template` `<div>` which is just one in your case. This is what *Descendant selector* is used for - To get specific elements, instead of all.

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){

    var result = $('.template li').clone(); //______Descendant selector
    $("ul").append(result);
});
```

---

While just `$('li')` selects `<li>s` from the whole DOM (initial + newly appended). The number of `li` elements resulting from `$('li')` will increase with the `append`.

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){
    var result = $('li:first').clone(); //______No descendant selector
    $("ul").append(result);
});
```

---

HTML at 2nd click, you can see there are two`<li>` at this point of time. So `$('li')` appends two elements and so on.

```
<div class="button">Click me</div>
<div class="template">
    <li>oink</li>
</div>

<ul>
    <li>oink</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this doesn't work?

Lets take it here:

```
<div class="button">Click me</div>
<div class="template">
    <li>oink</li>
</div>

<ul>
</ul>
```

---

As you can see in your markup there is one `li` in the markup but that is not a valid way to put any list item outside of `ul/ol`. Only `ul/ol`s can have the list items.

This is just a simple info but in your code the issue seems to be here:

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){
    var result = $('li').clone(); //______No descendant selector
    $("ul").append(result);
});
```

This line:

```
var result = $('li').clone();
```

returns you a collection of list items available in the page. So if you have one list item at first click then it returned only one `li` then append gets executed. so there is now two `li`s, now if you click then you would see two `li`s are getting appended.

#### Solution:

so the simplest solution is to use `:first`:

```
$(".button").on("click",function(){
    var result = $('li:first').clone(); //______No descendant selector
    $("ul").append(result);
});
```

now this line:

```
$('li:first').clone();
```

always returns you the first element found in the structure.

Comment: I know how I'm suppose to use li's I just threw this together to point out the problem

Comment: @william i guess you got it, where is the issue.